# Calculate rotation between 2 sets of Vectors

Tags: vector, matrix, rotation, linear-algebra, jama

I have 2 sets of 3D Vectors with N entries. I am trying to calculate the Rotation matrix which best aligns the first set with the second set.

I believe I can use the java library JAMA to accomplish this with Singular Value Decomposition or EigenValue Decomposition.

1) Is SVD or EVD the correct algorithm to use?

2) SVD/EVD in JAMA requires a Matrix. How do I populate the matrix based on my two sets of Vectors?

Comment: Would be best to include some code of your attempts so we can try and help you with it.

Comment: I haven't been able to attempt anything because I do not know how to populate the matrix required to call the JAMA functions. Or if these JAMA function are even the appropriate algorithms to call.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a 2-D version of what I believe you are describing (translating it to
3-D should be straightforward, except the m-matrix will be 3x3 and have
`shftx/y/z` entries).

An affine transformation of a point (x, y) to a point (u,
v) can be written as:

```
u    m11 m12    x      shftx
  =          *      +   
v    m21 m22    y      shfty

You can rewrite this as:

x y 0 0 1 0     m11      u
             *       =  
0 0 x y 0 1     m12      v

                m21

                m22

                shftx

                shfty
```

The reason for doing it this way is that you make the matrix on the left (with
the x/y/0/1 values) have up to as many rows as there are points in your data
set. If you call this matrix X, and the column vector on the right U, then the
problem becomes finding the least-squares solution m to the equation X * m = U.
You can solve this via (new `QRDecomposition(X)).solve(U)`. I should say that in
at least one version of QRDecomposition there was a bug in the code that was
assuming the wrong dimensions for the solution matrix, but I fixed it by
changing one line in the solve() method.